# Webscraping javascript rendered pages by inspecting and going to network tab and checking to see the request which is getting the data

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, python-requests

This is code I am using to get the reviews of Sephora webpage.

My problem is I want to get the reviews in the webpage https://www.sephora.com/product/crybaby-coconut-oil-shine-serum- P439093?skuId=2122083&icid2=just%20arrived:p439093

I want to inspect the webpage ,go to network tab  to check through all the request and find which url is returning my data.
I am not able to find the url which is returning the reviews.

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 chrome_path = (r"C:/Users/Connectm/Downloads/chromedriver.exe")

 driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
 driver.implicitly_wait(20) 
 driver.get("https://www.sephora.com/product/crybaby-coconut-oil-shine- 
 serum- P439093?skuId=2122083&icid2=just%20arrived:p439093")
 reviews = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ratings- 
 reviews"]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3][@data-comp()='Elipsis Box'])
 print(reviews.text)
```

Comment: There is a request to `reviews.json`. Maybe start there

Comment: Can you explain a little clearly?

Comment: Can anybody guide me?Can it be done?

Comment: If you check the Network tab in Chrome there is a request to `reviews.json` with some parameters after it. It should be possible to reverse engineer the parameters then you have the reviews as a json file.

Comment: @Trobol .Thanks for the suggestions.But i open inpsect over 1 review and under network tab i could not find reviews.json..Can u upload a pic?

Comment: You have to scroll down to where the reviews are for it to fetch it. [Try this link](https://api.bazaarvoice.com/data/reviews.json?Filter=ProductId%3AP439093&Sort=Helpfulness%3Adesc&Limit=30&Offset=0&Include=Products%2CComments&Stats=Reviews&passkey=rwbw526r2e7spptqd2qzbkp7&apiversion=5.4)

Comment: Thanks@Trobol.It works for you.But i think i am not able to find where i have to inspect.I am inspecting infront of the

Comment: Thanks@Trobol.It works for you.But i think i am not able to find where i have to inspect.I am inspecting infront of the  I love this hair serum!
I have tried countless hair products including Living Proof serum, Morrocanoil, Verb Ghost oil etc and NOTHING works as well as this serum. I have thick, long color treated hair and when used post blow drying or on days 2-4, it makes my hair look amazing. My mom even commented today on how nice my hair looked and all I did was brush

Comment: [Image](https://imgur.com/a/k8cmTo0)

Answer (score 0):

In the string you pass to `driver.get()` you have a white space that should not be there...

The correct string should be:

```
driver.get("https://www.sephora.com/product/crybaby-coconut-oil-shine-serum-P439093?skuId=2122083&icid2=just%20arrived:p439093")
```